# Store a userId in a local Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I try to store locally a unique identifier to each of my users and this is what I do

```js
const rand = function() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // remove `0.`
};

const getRandomToken = function() {
    return rand() + rand(); // to make it longer
};

window.chrome.storage.local.get('userId', (items) => {
    let userId = items.userId;
    
    if (userId === undefined) 
    {
        userId = getRandomToken();
        window.chrome.storage.local.set({userId: newId});//Line that causes an error message
    };
});
```

I put the right permission in the manifest I specify that I am on a minifest v3,
I have an error that appears I do not understand why.
It is this error : https://ibb.co/J7HzbH5 ;
If you have a question or even another idea to be able to generate a random token, I am interested thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The error message clearly says you don't have `newId` defined and indeed you don't. You have `userId`.

Comment: Yes I finally found what I needed to do that's it
window.chrome.storage.local.set({userId: userId})